# can't receive UDP packets on my local running tomcat webserver

Tags: java, android, servlets, udp, httpconnection

I  have developed a tomcat server local, that has a UDP connection that receives udp packets. The server also has a httpconnection with a Android application. The httpconnection is working perfect but the UDP connection is now failing and i dont recieve any UDP packets anymore. I get a SocketTimeoutException. It is very strange that i can ping the server sending the udp packets.

```
public void connect() throws IOException 
    {
         //Creates a datagramsocket, bound to the specified local address.
          socket = new DatagramSocket();
         //Sends a datagrampacket from this socket.

         DatagramPacket sendDatagramPacket = new DatagramPacket(message, message.length, local,
                 server_port);
       //Sends a datagrampacket from this socket.
         socket.send(sendDatagramPacket);
         System.out.println(sendDatagramPacket.getData().toString());

    }


    public void receive() throws IOException 
    {

         // Prepare a UDP-Packet that can contain the data we want to receive
        DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(message, message.length);
        // Receive the UDP-Packet

      socket.setSoTimeout(30000);
        socket.receive(receivePacket);
        tryRead(receivePacket.getData());
        System.out.println("receivePacket.getData()");

    }
```

Comment: "I dont recieve any UDP packet anymore", so it has worked before? What did you change since then? Both code and your network environment.

Comment: I had first 1 connection from the server thats sends UDP packets to the Android application. Now i installed a tomcat server on the pc local that connects to the udp server and has a htppconnection to the Android application.

Comment: Any errors in catalina.log?

Comment: noo, i have checked nothing, i only get the SocketTimeoutException. Is this a port problem?

Comment: UDP is often blocked by firewalls and/or routers.  Are you sure that there is nothing blocking the packets?  Ping uses ICMP, a different protocol than UDP.